# Extending stylesheet block

Tags: symfony, twig

I have stylesheet block in base layout:

```
  {% stylesheets
       filter='cssrewrite'
      'bundles/static/css/main.css'
  %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
  {% endstylesheets %}
```

I am wonder if I can extend this block in sub template. Add another CSS link or links.

Could somebody give me any advice? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Of course, it's possible.

But currently, you don't have stylesheet block. You use the stylesheets tag.

Just add a block like this:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {% stylesheets
       filter='cssrewrite'
      'bundles/static/css/main.css'
    %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
```

And in others templates:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {% stylesheets
       filter='cssrewrite'
      'another-css-file'
    %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
```

Don't forget to call the `parent` function to not override parent stylesheets.

Comment: Is this possible using this technique to merge all files in one, so one <link> tag will appear?

Comment: nope, you can't (or I don't know the solution and I want to know it).