# Add file to stylesheet tag in sub template

Tags: symfony, twig

My question is related too:
[Extending stylesheet block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114033/extending-stylesheet-block)

I am wonder if I can add other CSS files to "array" of files declared in stylesheet tag in base template, so, e.g. all files will merged in one link tag.

Answer (score 1):

No, currently it's not possible.

I guess you can completely override main stylesheets tag, so you copy/paste whole stylesheets tag array form base file to your template and add your desired file to it.

But why not just add the files to main tag in the first place? If it's optimization you're worried about - trust me, it's minimal..