# Symfony/Twig: Extending stylesheet block from an extended bundle

Tags: symfony, twig

I'd like to extend the `stylesheets` blocks from inside a bundle I've created to extend `FOSUserBundle`.

[This is how to extend from inside the same bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114033/extending-stylesheet-block), but I want to extend from another bundle that extends a third-party bundle.

This is the code:

```
{# src/MyNamespace/UserBundle/views/layout.html.twig #}
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {% stylesheets filter='scssphp,cssrewrite' output='css/app.css'
    'bundles/mynamespace/scss/Profile.scss'
    %}
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}

{% block title %}My title{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    {% block fos_user_content %}{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

So, basically, I've extended the `FOSUserBundle` creating another bundle in my `src` directory [as explained here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html#overriding-resources-templates-routing-etc).

The code of my `base.html.twig template is this:

```
{# app/Resources/views/base.html.twig #}
...
    <head>
        ...
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
        <meta name="description" content="{% block metaDescription %}{% endblock %}" />
        {% include('::_common/Stylesheets.html.twig') %}
...
```

And this is the included `Stylesheets.html.twig`:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {% stylesheets filter='scssphp,cssrewrite' output='css/app.css'
    'bundles/app/css/bootstrap.css'
    ...
    %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
```

The problem is that the CSS from `src/MyNamespace/UserBundle/views/layout.html.twig` is never included in the page, also if it is installed with `app/console asstes:install` and then dumped with `app/console assetic:dump`.

The CSS is generated and put in `web/css/app_Profile_1.css` but is never included in the pages (not in home page or other `AppBundle` pages, not in `MyNamespaceUserBundle` pages.

Also adding the line `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />` to the `src/MyNamespace/UserBundle/views/layout.html.twig` block, the CSS isn't included.

Obviously, if I include the stylesheet directly from `_common/Stylesheets.html.twig` the file is correctly included.
So, it seems there is something break.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Without the `<link rel="stylesheet">` in the `{% block stylesheets %}` in layout.html.twig, it's not going to output the link for Profile.scss.

More importantly, though, is that `{% include %}` and `{% block %}` do not work quite the way you think they do in the presence of `{% extends %}`. The combination is a little weird, so some background first.

A `{% block %}` is simply a named wrapper around some content. In the absence of `{% extends %}`, a block is immediately output where it is defined. (Think of it as if you defined a function, and then immediately called it.)

When you extend another template, however, block definitions in the "global scope" of the extending template replace the definitions of the block in the extended template. This is a re-definition only; the block is still being called at the same place it was in the parent template.

`{% include %}` renders another template and inserts *the results of the evaluation* in-line. While it has access to the current context's variables, it is otherwise it's own separate renderer. Importantly, it does *not* substitute itself with the template code as you are expecting.

So what is happening is this:

`layout.html.twig` extends `base.html.twig`. `layout.html.twig` defines a stylesheets block (but does not emit it). `base.html.twig` includes `Stylesheets.html.twig`, so `base.html.twig` gains the result of evaluating `Stylesheets.html.twig` (so you get the contents of the `{% stylesheets %}` tag, but importantly, *not the fact that there was even a block there at all*.

Then, because there is no place in `base.html.twig` where there actually is a `{% block stylesheets %}`, the block defined in `layout.html.twig` never gets called.

The solution is to move the `{% block stylesheets %}` into `base.html.twig`. If you want to keep the actual stylesheet definitions in the `Stylesheets.html.twig`, then you can do it like this:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {% include('::_common/Stylesheets.html.twig') %}
{% endblock %}
```

And remove the block tag (but not the stylesheet content itself) from `Stylesheets.html.twig`. That should give you the desired result.