# Twig Block content into Include

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm trying to put `{% block body %}` into an `{% include 'bundle::...' %}`. Here's my code below:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}{{ id }}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    {% include 'scraperBundle::Event/sideLeft.html.twig' %}
    {% include 'scraperBundle::Event/sideRight.html.twig' %}

{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    stuff here to go ingo block body
{% endblock %}
```

The problem is everything loads correctly except my `{% block body %}` does not go into the place it should, which is in the `{% include 'scraperBundle::Event/sideLeft.html.twig' %}` file here:

```
<div class="event-info">
    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
</div>
```

I'm not well versed in Twig, anyone know the correct method or how to do this?

Thanks.

============== EDIT ==============

Can I have nested `{% block nameof %}`?

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}{{ id }}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    {% embed 'scraperBundle::Event/sideLeft.html.twig' %}

        {% block body %}
        {% endblock %}

    {% endembed %}

    {% embed 'scraperBundle::Event/sideRight.html.twig' %}

{% endblock %}
```

============== EDIT 2 (Working) ==============

Added second `{% endembed %}` and now it works. I guess you can, indeed, have nested `{% block %}` stuff.

Can I have nested `{% block nameof %}`?

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}{{ id }}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    {% embed 'scraperBundle::Event/sideLeft.html.twig' %}

        {% block body %}
        {% endblock %}

    {% endembed %}

    {% embed 'scraperBundle::Event/sideRight.html.twig' %}
    {% endembed %}

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot override block from `include`d template. What you're looking for is [`embed`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/embed.html):

```
# template1.html.twig

{% embed "template2.html.twig" %}
    {% block override_me %}
        This will override "HAI" text
    {% endblock %}
{% endembed %}

# template2.html.twig

Something here
{% block override_me %}HAI{% endblock %}
```

Comment: in `base.html.twig` I have a block named content. In what I've listed above, I have a `block` with those two (now embedded) files. Can you have nested blocks? [note: I listed the edit code above so you can for clarity]

Answer (score 1):

You can't specify or override blocks from an included template. Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34670519/5760706) to a similar question for some background information as to *why* that doesn't work.

[{% embed %}](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/embed.html) will do what you need, though.

For your second question: blocks can be nested. Nested blocks are quite common, in practice.